# Attempt to find a synonym of word "old"

Tags: meaning, adjectives, synonyms, objects

Few weeks ago, while reading some texts a new vocabulary encountred. when translated it via English to English online dictionary, one of the synonym was the word "old"?
To have or to put the aforementioned word in a sensible sentences, it could be:

> ..for the sake of the OLD days.

The synonym found online it contains, as far as I remember, the letter "y".

Can any of you help me to find out what that synonm was?

Comment: In days of *yore*, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

From the MacOS thesaurus:

> in the old days: bygone, past, former, olden, of old, previous, early, earlier, earliest; medieval, ancient, classical, primeval, primordial, prehistoric, antediluvian. ANTONYMS modern, recent.

I suspect *bygone* is the word you're looking for.